# How to make 0,0 on matplotlib graph on the bottom left corner?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a graph that looks like this using mathplotlib
[image: graph]

However the margins between where the line actually starts and the edges of the graph are unnecessary, do you know how I can get rid of the margins so 0,0 starts at the corner?

For example, I want it to look like this [image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
plt.xlim([0, x_max])
plt.ylim([0, y_max])
```

You can easily get the values of (x_max, y_max) from your data.

Comment: keyword arguments `ymin` and `xmin` might be used, this way you do not have to calculate `x_max` and `y_max`, for instance `plt.xlim(xmin=0.0)`.